# Alternative to multiple use of if-else in the code base

Tags: c++, c, coding-style

I have a huge chunk of code that works on say two version of some param , let say ver1 and ver2.

Version is a run time field and i intend to keep it as, so that i don't have to build the code with different flags and same lib files can be used for both versions.

Now, there are different fields that are applicable for ver1 and some for ver2.

So in the code at multiple places i have to do

```
if(ver1) {
    // set fields specific to ver1
}
else {
    // set fields specific to ver2
}
```

I don't like the idea of putting so may if statements in the code, as the code tends to look ugly.

Any alternatives this ?

I was thinking some generic inline / macro definition where a field is set only if flag passed is true ?

Also, on the optimization side , should not be expensive than if else

@edit -- some details of internal organization of code

Can't post the details of code. But one important matter of fact is that its a huge legacy code which needs upgrade with backward compatibility.

The version param is passed to each class to decide what field is to be set and which to ignore.

Comment: How about write two versions of functions?

Comment: if you have a lot of side effects in branches and different versions try to reduce branches by refactoring. When you know what kind of fields are commonly set together start to extract those to functions. if possible common function, then extract an interface. See also: Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code

Answer (score 3):

One often used solution is to have two classes that represent version 1 and version 2, with a common base-class defining the interface with virtual functions. So, you only get one if/else, and then the virtual function table takes care of picking the right function.

If that's not a plausible solution, then if-else is the clearest way, I'd say.

Comment: @Dexter Your question is very vague on the details. Maybe you should describe why it doesn't work on your scenario. What is your scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that using functions. The basic purpose of functions is to reduce code redundancy.

```
#define VERSION1 25
#define VERSION2 55

void checkVersion(int vers)
    {
       switch(vers)
       {
         case VERSION1:
              code_Depending_On_Version1();
              break;


         case VERSION2:
              code_Depending_On_Version2();
              break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that there are multiple fields, that are set depending upon version and at different location in the code base. I would end up creating some many functions.

Comment: if you mean your code is written like nested if-else (like people do in school), then you seriously need to rethink your coding approach. My opinion is to create a function for code related to version 1 and same for version 2.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just cosmetic, then:

```
void blabla0(bool ver1)
{
 if(ver1)
 {
  blabla1();
  return;
 }
 blabla2(); // save one else and two brackets, but get a return :-(
}
```

If you always know the parameter at compile time, then I would use templates

```
template<bool ver> blabla0()
{
 if(ver1)
 {
  blabla1();
  return;
 }
 blabla2();
}
```

This is both efficient (the compiler will build two specialized version of the function) and clear.

I forgot another one:

```
void blabla0(bool ver1)
{
 ver1 ? blabla1(): blabla2();
}
```

Or use a base virtual class with two derived classes specialized for each version, as suggested by Mats Petersson.